# Using generic types in Constructor of an VB.NET Windows.Form

Tags: vb.net

I define a class with generic type (No Problem).

```
Public Class clsAbsDatoCodDesc(Of TipoDatoCodigo)

  Dim Codigo As TipoDatoCodigo
  Dim Descripcion As String

End Class
```

Now I want to use a parameter of this class in a Windows.form, but a I can't:

```
dim x as clsAbsDatoCodDesc(Of Integer)

Dim vloFrm As New FrmCodDes10(x)
```

The problem is in the definition of the form:

```
Public Class FrmCodDes10

Dim vmoData As clsAbsDatoCodDesc(Of TipoDatoCodigo)

Public Sub New(ByVal vpoData As clsAbsDatoCodDesc(Of TipoDatoCodigo))

  InitializeComponent()

  vmoData = vpoData

End Sub

End Class
```

-With  abobe code I get error TipoDatoCodigo not defined, but I cannot define it because if I put:

```
Public Class FrmCodDes10(Of TipoDatoCodigo)
```

then InitializeComponent appears as not defined.

Comment: Do you actually have a type `TipoDatoCodigo` or is that supposed to represent any type?

Comment: I think the problem is you are using the type as the identifier in the class declaration. Even if the compiler differentiates between the two it makes the code difficult to follow.

Comment: You are trying to pass a variable Of Integer to a constructor that wants Of TipoDatoCodigo.  They are not the same type of course.  It is not clear what you intended, but surely you just need to declare the `x` variable correctly.  If you want to make the form class generic then you must use a generic type parameter, consider Of T instead.  Do be careful, the designer cannot support a generic base type so you'd be wise to declare it NotInheritable